# Displaying modal login on launch - over UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'd like to display a login modal in the center of the screen upon launch, but I get a blank background and the modal disregards my position code.

I have an iOS application based on UITableView. When the user first opens the app, I'd like to display a modal login window in the center of the screen. In my main view controller's viewDidLoad, I set all the data used by my UITableViewController. I then call my modal window with the following (slightly changed for example purposes):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    TenKeyPad *passwordEntry = [[[TenKeyPad alloc] initWithValues:@"" PasswordEntry:TRUE] autorelease];
    passwordEntry.delegate = self;

    passwordEntry.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    passwordEntry.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    passwordEntry.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320, 460); // iphone screen is 320 x 480 (-20px that would normally be the toolbar)
    passwordEntry.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(768/2, 1024/2 + 10);

    [self presentViewController:passwordEntry animated:NO completion:nil];
        
    [passwordEntry release];
}
```

I would expect to have the modal password window appear over the table view, but, instead, it's shown in the top left corner of the display with a dark gray background. However, if I call this modal with the exact same code later in the application, it behaves as expected/desired. **What is the proper way or time to load the modal so that it displays over my tableView?**

### Screenshots

#### Faulty

[image: Faulty login window]

#### Desired/Expected

[image: Desired/Expected login window]

Answer (score 1):

I have had hard times with this functionality as well. I have not found a proper way to set the size of the modal from the start. I would try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    LoginViewController *controller = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:^{
        // resize
        controller.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-160, self.view.frame.size.height/2-230, 320, 460);
    }];
}
```

This does what you need but the animation will not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about anonymous callback blocks. Very cool. Unfortunately this didn't work. After MUCH fighting, I implemented a hack where I show the modal after a millisecond delay using performSelector:WithObject:afterDelay. This is hardly satisfying, but it gets the job done.

Comment: No problem. I just started writing a small group of classes to make a better solution to this problem. The idea is to create custom looking modals the "right" way. Check out my project and let me know if you are interested. https://github.com/lopeza511/BGPartialModals